# How to get gettimeofday (llvm::Function* ) with call & bitcast?

Tags: llvm, call

```
89   %14 = call i32 (%struct.timeval*, i8*, ...) bitcast (i32 (...)* @gettimeofday to i32 (%struct.timeval*, i8*, ...)*)(%struct.timeval* %11, i8* null)
```

I want to get value (Function*) of gettimeofday.

This is what I try to do. But it does not work.

Value* opnd = CurrentInst->getOperand(CurrentInst->getNumOperands() -1);

How to get calledFunction ?

Answer (score 0):

This method is called just as you wrote in your question: [getCalledFunction()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallBase.html#ae001f2763f387fe3e9a24319f53263aa). Remember to `cast<CallInst>(CurrentInst)` first.